# How to proceed when an accepted answer from months/years ago is inaccurate and/or wrong?

Tags: discussion, support

I have spotted a question with 10K+ views and an accepted answer with 10 votes:

[What is the difference between a mode and a scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mode-and-a-scale)

It happens that the accepted answer has inaccuracies which do not fit a simple comment to be fixed, and there are another fifteen answers with lots to do in common.

My question is about whether it is worthy or not to try adding a more accurate answer to such old question with an established (yet questionable) answer. I just *know* it will not get enough visibility and probably will have no chance to be a game-changing answer, given the time elapsed since the establishment of such question.

I feel like I have the duty to make things clearer, but on the other hand, I just know it will most likely be some wasted research lost among lots of background noise.

What do you think?

Comment: Definitely add an answer, and at least leave a comment pointing out the things that you think are wrong with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

First, do note that the accepted answer is entirely up to the question poster.  It's to indicate what helped them, not to say "this is correct".  (The person who needed to ask is probably the least qualified to make that distinction, after all.)

The language of that answer seems a little imprecise, but generally correct.  If you have clarifications or small changes, you should edit.

If you feel that the problem is more significant and the other answers don't do it either, you should post your own answer.  I don't think that a question with 10k views will "not get enough visibility".  Stack Exchange is gamified, and if you're going for rep/votes/views that's up to you, but you should consider contributing for other reasons.  The asker has been active within the month, and will be notified of a new answer the next time they visit, and again given the 10k+ views you can expect future readers to see it as well.